# What is the meaning of the ending of "What Lies Below"?

Tags: what-lies-below

At the end of the film *What Lies Below*, "John Smith" reveals his true nature. We already suspected that he was some kind of

> lamprey-type monster who wanted to seduce Michelle for some sort of sinister purpose.

But then things get *weird*.

It appears that "John Smith" has a number of clones who assist him. I suppose there was a hint at this when Liberty saw someone who appeared to possibly be identical to John Smith, but that still does not explain why he has clones in the first place. Nor, certainly, does it provide any hint as to why one of his clones appeared at the end, and appeared to break open a wall, behind which was Michelle Wells (or her corpse). Then, by all appearances, several more clones appear to do exactly the same thing. It is difficult to make heads or tails of this.

Then "John Smith" seems to implant some sort of glowing thing in Liberty, claiming that they do not have much time. I suppose he is worried about the fact that she called the police (but not about any questions they might ask about the sudden disappearance of three people and all the identical quintuplets walking around?). But then we see her underwater, in a diamond-shaped pod or casket, surrounding by orange-haired people in identical caskets. I suppose this might call back to an earlier line when John told her that her hair was starting to turn orange, but if this has a meaning besides sounding creepy, it is unclear.

In short, what is the meaning of the ending? Why does John Smith have clones? Why does Michelle have clones? Why is Liberty put in a pod and surrounded by people with orange hair (who may also be clones)?

Comment: The author was interviewed here and gave some basic answers: https://ew.com/movies/what-lies-below-ending-netflix/

Comment: @DoscoJones - That is not what I expected, although the newspaper article about a Netflix film about a "sexy MERMAN" leaving viewers confused certainly is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article given in the comments by another [user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/22431/dosco-jones) explains most of the confusing elements of the film.

So, first John is an alien.

> **So what's going on with the end of the film? Is John an alien?**
>
> I've heard the [cat] is out the bag because, if you put on the
> subtitles, it apparently says "Alien noises." So, yes, I would say he
> is a species from another planet. I don't want to unpack it much more
> than that. I would say, if you missed anything, maybe go back to the
> time that Libby drives the car down to see into the lake and look at
> what she sees. We could get more into the weeds of it, if you want.

Second, his clones are tailored to be attractive to different types of people. In typical evil alien fashion, he is interested in collecting human beings for his [extraterrestrial experiments.](https://ew.com/movies/what-lies-below-ending-netflix/)

> Okay. I saw it as John is designed by his species. He is an
> exoskeleton that has been designed as a Venus flytrap. Although the
> exoskeleton is the same, the algorithm changes for each one. One of
> them is a scientist and kind of nerdy. The other one is kind of a
> hipster. The other one is kind of rock 'n' roll. They do it to attract
> different personalities but they're always after the same thing, which
> is very clear in the last shot. They're collecting specimen. And I
> would say to anyone who felt awkward throughout the film, go back, and
> listen to John's lines, and imagine he's speaking about Libby and
> Michelle as specimens instead of people, and then all of a sudden his
> word choices make more sense.

The Johns specifically are interested in people with red hair, thus the weird line and the plethora of orange-haired people at the end.

> **Ah! Okay. The aliens are only interested in redheads. Why?**
>
> Yeah, it's like a genetic anomaly. I was looking for something that is
> a little bit different in us as humans, as far as our genetic code,
> and I found that red hair, it has all these really interesting traits.
> I felt that that might be a reason why John's species could procreate
> with us, that's the only way he can is because of that one gene. It's
> all part of this one grand experiment that's basically John Smith's
> species trying to figure out how they could come to this planet and
> take over.

As side note, the science of this is kind of shaky. There are multiple genes that can produce orange hair, and none of them are so essential to reproduction that they could enable procreation with aliens, who would not be genetically compatible anyway.

But in any case, that explains why he does not kill Liberty. It also explains why he would be interested, not just in seducing her mother, but also in having a child with her. Presumably the child would have the appropriate genes.

So in the end, John is not a creepy human man who wants to have sex with both Liberty and her mother. He is actually...ummmm, a creepy alien who is also (disguised as?) a man who wants to have sex with Liberty's mother and probably her eventually, in order to produce more orange-haired test specimens?